# SQL - Not sure if I should use joins to resolve this query

Tags: sql

I have the following question presented to me:

"Write a SQL command to display for each student who has an average result of greater than 60, the student’s name, the total number of attempts the student has had at all exams, and the student’s average result."

The tables I am working with for this are:
Mark, with fields examID(PK), studentID(PK), result, occurred, noOfAttempts

And Student with the fields id(PK) and Name.

The field StudentID in mark is also a foreign key to Student.

Anyways this is what I've come up with so far:

```
SELECT S.name, AVG(M.RESULT) FROM STUDENT S, MARK M 
WHERE S.ID = (
SELECT studentID FROM
MARK
WHERE 60 < 
(SELECT AVG(result) from MARK));
```

But it is igiving me a "not a single group function" error. I've tried using some other joins but that also resulted in a whole ton of errors so I'm pretty sure I did those wrong.

At this point I am nearly completely lost. I know that the "deepest" subquery will return me the student ID's that have an average result bigger than 60, but when I try to return all student ID's that match that particular ID it doesnt work. I'm also not sure how to count the total no. of attempts in this query so I didnt even attempt that for now.

Table data:
[image: Mark]

[image: Student]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
SELECT 
    S.name, SUM(M.noOfAttempts) AS attempts, AVG(M.RESULT) AS result
FROM
    STUDENT S
INNER JOIN
    MARK M ON (S.ID = M.studentID)
GROUP BY
    S.ID, S.name
HAVING 
    AVG(M.RESULT) > 60
```

Comment: Lashane, whilst it does correctly select the two students with the results specified, it seems to go a bit haywire from then on. The number of attempts I get for Jones is 5, when it should be 2, and his average result is also off. Weirdly for the second student, TAO, it actually does it all correctly.

Comment: @MateuszJ can you edit question and post data in both tables?

Comment: I added screencaps of both tables if that helps.

Comment: @MateuszJ ok, you have duplicate names, I've updated query

Comment: Ok, thank you, that works :) The only problem is we're meant to do this in an exam tomorrow but this calibre of answer comes nowhere near what we did in the lab and I'm kinda afraid there's a more obvious solution I am missing :/ I dont recall having to use "group by" at all in the labs and I dont know if there was an obvious-er solution or if this particular exam paper was just mean.

Comment: To use aggregate functions like sum or avg you have to use group by